# asp.net panel loses viewstate on postback

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a web page with an update panel in it.
Inside the update panel I have a panel with a user control like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updatePanel" runat="server" ChildrenAsTriggers="true" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Panel ID="pnlFiles" runat="server" EnableViewState="true">
        <files:FilesControl runat="server" ID="filesControl" />
    </asp:Panel>
</ContentTemplate>
```

I have a list of checkboxes that whenever the user checks one of them I want to add another `FilesControl` to that panel
so I am doing it like this:

```
FilesControl files = (FilesControl)LoadControl("~/UserControls/FilesControl.ascx");
files.ID = XXX;
pnlFiles.Controls.Add(files);
```

But on every postback (every checkbox checked) the panel loses the last state and the controls added are wiped out, so the panel actually returns to its initial state every time and I can't ad more and more controls to it.
I enabled view state and it didn't help.
What am I missing out here ?

Comment: Do you add the control to the page on every postback in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load` with the same ID as before?

Comment: The ID is unique, I generate it. I add the controls on the checkbox checked change event `chkCompare_CheckedChanged`

Comment: While it is perfectly fine to add a control dynamically in an event, it is necessary to **re**-create this control on the subsequent postbacks. That must be done in `Page_Load` at the latest (better: `Page_Init`). So you need to store somewhere which controls you have already added to be able to re-create them. Maybe it is sufficient to store the control-count in the `ViewState`.

Comment: But the panel is hard coded and I add controls to it, so mustn't it have a view state of its own that he stores the controls added to it in ? I can try and manage a viewstate of my own but it seems not right if the panel already has a view state of its own. no ?

Comment: The control's viewstate is not used to persist dynamic controls. It is just used to store f.e. the `Text` property of a `TextBox` if it doesn't have it's default value.

Comment: So I should store the controls I added in the ViewState object and then re-add them to the panel on `Page_Load` ?

Comment: No, you shouldn't store the _controls_ in the `ViewState` but the information that is necessary to re-create them. How do you know what you need to add? Of course you could also use a webdatabound control like `Repeater`, `DataList`or `GridView` where you only need a `DataSource` and the persisting stuff is made automatically.

Comment: I can re-create them manually according to the checked checkboxes. So in fact on every postback I'm recreating all the controls again and again... right ?

Comment: Yes, that is what is done with all controls even if you add them declaratively(on aspx). But those controls are re-created automatically by ASP.NET. All variables are disposed at the end of the page's life-cycle.

Comment: Thank you very very much for all of your answers and your explanations. I will take your advice :-)

Comment: Can you please add your solution as an answer so I could mark it as answer ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As requested, my comments as answer:

You need to add  the control(s) to the page on every postback in `Page_Init` or `Page_Load`(at the latest) with the same ID as before.

> The ID is unique, I generate it. I add the controls on the checkbox
>   checked change event chkCompare_CheckedChanged

While it is perfectly fine to add a control dynamically in an event, it is necessary to **re**-create this control on the subsequent postbacks. That must be done in `Page_Load` at the latest (better: `Page_Init`). So you need to store somewhere which controls you have already added to be able to re-create them. Maybe it is sufficient to store the control-count in the `ViewState`.

> So I should store the controls I added in the ViewState object and
>   then re-add them to the panel on Page_Load ?

No, you shouldn't store the controls in the `ViewState` but the *information* that is necessary to re-create them. How do you know what you need to add? Of course you could also use a webdatabound control like `Repeater`, `DataList` or `GridView` where you only need to assign a `DataSource` and the persisting stuff is done automatically for you.

That is what is done with all controls even if you add them declaratively(on aspx). But those controls are re-created automatically by ASP.NET. All variables are disposed at the end of the page's [life-cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719775%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) since the communication between the client and the server is stateless and disconnected.

Comment: As prommised: Marked as answer :-)

Comment: Additional info can be found here: [Dynamically Created Controls in ASP.NET](http://www.singingeels.com/Articles/Dynamically_Created_Controls_in_ASPNET.aspx)

Comment: @LiranFriedman: or more in depth: [dynamic controls](http://goo.gl/qniur3) and [ViewState](http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate)